# SSL connection for sever and client on separate hostings

Tags: ssl, heroku, netlify, mern

I have a MERN application.
My client is hosted by Netlify. 
My server is hosted by Heroku.
And how can I provide SSL for my web app? Do I need SSL certificate only on my client or only on my server or client and server? I don't fully understand this moment.